# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new on laravel , I didn't write any code yet but when I open my project it gives me this error , anyone can help me to solve it ? 
[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: Please, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try `http://localhost:8000` since it seems like you already started development server in your local machine using `php artisan serve` while you were on your project root via terminal.

Or you can try from begining:

1. Go to your project root from terminal / cmd
2. Run `php artisan serve`
3. Now try `http://localhost:8000` which is equivalent to `http://localhost/laravel/public` , considering **laravel** is your project folder name.